# Pass preprocessing variable to NVCC for compiling CUDA?

Tags: cuda, c-preprocessor, nvcc

When I compile my CUDA code with NVCC and I have already defined a preprocessing variable in the code, e.g. `#define DEBUG_OUTPUT 0`, is there a way to overwrite such a variable on the fly when compiling? I tried so specify the NVCC option `-DDEBUG_OUTPUT=1` but this doesn't work: It gives me:

> warning C4005: 'DEBUG_OUTPUT': Macro-Redefinition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever you specify after -D, it gets defined before processing the input files. However, it does not remove the definitions that occur in the file. So, if you write `-DDEBUG_OUTPUT` but then you have `#define DEBUG_OUTPUT` in the file, the latter is a redefinition of the former. To handle that case, you can write in the file:

```
//if not specified earlier (e.g. by -D parameter)
#ifndef DEBUG_OUTPUT
//set it now to some default value
#define DEBUG_OUTPUT 0
#endif
```

Note, it has actually nothing to do with nvcc. Same behaviour appears in C/C++.

Comment: okay thanks! how can I specify the value of more than one variable and not only define it? Something like `-DSOME_VAR=1000,OTHER_VAR=2000`? Edit: Figured it out by testing, it's `-DSOME_VAR=1000 -DOTHER_VAR=2000`.

Answer (score 1):

If a preprocessor macro is already defined and you are sure that you don't need whatever it was originally, just redefine it conditionally:

```
#ifdef MYMACRO
#  undef MYMACRO
#endif
#define MYMACRO my macro content
```